# Can you call more than one converter on a property binding in xaml, and if so how

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, converters

I have a button defined in xaml whose visibility is bound to a dependency property using the standard BooleanToVisibility converter like so.

```
 Visibility="{Binding Path=GoToButtonVisibility,Converter={StaticResource booltovis}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Now I also have a textbox whose read only property I would like to bind to the visibility of the button I mentioned above, except that it needs to be the opposite, so if the button isn't visible it's read only will be true, if not it will be false.

That meant I needed some way of having Not x in my xaml.  Stack overflow to the rescue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539797/xaml-binding-to-the-opposite-of-another-element) answer.

So now I have a nice NotConverter, however I cant simply do something like this;

```
 IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=PART_GoToButton, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}"
```

because the NotConverter will throw an invalid cast exception.  I have no problem with that and I understand why.  I do however like the principle of the not converter so my question(s) are as follows.

1) in the xaml itself is it possible to invoke both converters on the same like such that they would produce the desired result.
2) assuming 1 isn't possible then it suggests the need for a visibility to Boolean convertor.  As the BooleanToVisibility converter is builtin I'm not sure how the convert and Convertback functions have been written and therefore how I would effectively reverse them.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just bind to the same property, but through your not converter. Your code for the text box would thus be:

```
 IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=GoToButtonVisibility, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}"
```

Your NotConverter is this:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is bool)
            return !(bool)value;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is bool)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

There's no need to get the visibility of the button from the UI.

Comment: Hi Chris  I'm sure that this is correct, particularly given the fact that the logic is so blindingly obvious that I really ought to have seen it myself.  However when I apply it it doesn't work, and putting a breakpoint on the converter's convert function indicates that it's not being called.  I'm not getting any xaml parse exceptions which suggests that the converter is correctly referenced and defined in the xaml.  Have marked the question up in the meantime and as soon as I can figure out why it isn't working and get it to work hope to accept it as well.

Comment: @DomSinclair - if you've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and are raising the property changed event for `GoToButtonVisibility` then this should work. I take it that the button changes state correctly?

Comment: Oh yes the button does, that's what's throwing me.

Comment: Could it possible be connected with the fact that GoToButtonVisibility has a defaultValue of False and therefefore if it's not explicitly set to true onpropertychanged isn't called and therefore isreadonly will presumably fall back on its default of false?

Comment: @DomSinclair it should cope with the default case. You could make an explicit `RaisePropertyChanged("GoToButtonVisibility");` (or what ever you've called that method) once the view's been loaded. But that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This is within a CustomControl so GoToButtonVisibility is a dependency property and as such it's onGoToButtonVisibilityChanged isn't automatically called when the default value is allowed to prevail.  Custom Controls are still new to me so I suspect that there's something else I need to be doing in these particular types.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an aggregate converter like this:

```
   public class ValueConverterGroup : List<IValueConverter>, IValueConverter
   {
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
      return this.Aggregate(value, (current, converter) => converter.Convert(current, targetType, parameter, language));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
```

then combine converters in xaml:

```
<conv:ValueConverterGroup x:Key="booleanToInvertedVisibilityConverter">
  <conv:BooleanNegationConverter />
  <conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
</conv:ValueConverterGroup>
```

and then use that aggregate converter just as you would use any other:

```
             <Button Name="btnBuy" Content="Buy full version" Command="{Binding Path=CommandBuy}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Visibility="{Binding Path=IsPaidVersion, Converter={StaticResource booleanToInvertedVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: `ValueConverterGroup` could implement ConvertBack as well : `return this.Reverse().Aggregate(value, (current, converter) => converter.Convert(current, targetType, parameter, language));`

Answer (score 0):

Using the aggregate converter described in @Jogy's answer you can even use the following markup extension :

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(IValueConverter))]
public class ConverterChainExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public ConverterChainExtension()
    {
    }

    public ConverterChainExtension(string converterNames)
    {
        this.ConverterNames = converterNames;
    }

    public string Separator { get; set; }

    [ConstructorArgument("converterNames")]
    public string ConverterNames { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        List<IValueConverter> converters = new List<IValueConverter>();
        if (this.ConverterNames != null)
        {
            foreach (string converterName in this.ConverterNames.Split(new[] { this.Separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                if (new StaticResourceExtension(converterName).ProvideValue(serviceProvider) is IValueConverter converter)
                {
                    converters.Add(converter);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Couldn't find the converter with name : '{converterName}'");
                }
            }
        }

        return new YourAggregateConverter(converters);
    }
}
```

After declaring the converters you want as resources (`BoolInverterConverter` and `BoolToVisibilityConverter`), you can use the markup extension like this :

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={ConverterChain Separator=/, ConverterNames=BoolInverterConverter/BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```