# WPF MVVM dependency Property Get negative value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two buttons, SEND and UNSEND. I want to enable or disable the buttons using the boolean `IsSended`.

I've created a dependency property which can be used to enable one of the buttons, but how I can take the negative value to control the other button?

VIEW

```
dxb:BarButtonItem Content="SEND" IsEnabled="{Binding !IsSent}" 
dxb:BarButtonItem Content="UNSEND" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSent}"
```

VIEWMODEL

```
public Boolean IsSent
{
   get { return (Boolean) GetValue(IsSendedProperty); }
   set { SetValue(IsSendedProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSendedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSent", typeof(Boolean), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(Boolean)));
```

Comment: Not sure why are you introducing `DependencyProperty`. It can be `bool IsSended` property and you can use [value converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580467/wpf-property-data-binding-to-negate-the-property) to bind to negate property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of was to do this in WPF; `IValueConverters`, `DataTemplate` or overriding the `ControlTemplate`.

It is hard to know which would be the best in the long run for your particular application, but the simplest to show here is the `IValueConverter`.

Add a class called, for example, `NegateBoolConverter`

```
public class NegateBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

Create an instance of this class in XAML (I put all my converters all the way up in the `App.xaml`, but you could put it in the `<Window.Resources>` section.

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:NegateBoolConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
  </Window.Resources>
```

where `local:` is a namespace to the converter class

Then your binding becomes:

```
  <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="SEND" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSended, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
```